# Can't find the CSS error

Tags: css

MY IDE gives me an parse error and some styles aren't evaluated.

```
#scroll-down::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background: #64c8d7;
    transform: skew(0deg, 25deg);
}
#scroll-down::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background: #64c8d7;
    transform: skew(0deg, -25deg);
}​
```

Comment: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: Appears to be an extra character on the last line, which for some reason is hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy and paste your code on jsfiddle.net and you can see there is `/u200b` (Zero Length White Space Unicode) character in the end of your stylesheet which is white space.

Comment: Thanks alot! That was it.